# What's the diff between dbo.aspnet_Users and dbo.aspnetUsers?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, roles

VS 2013, Framework 4.5.1 ...

I ran Aspnet_regsql.exe to create the schema. It created the tables with an underscore in them:  aspnet_Users for example. It also created the associated stored procedures. Those stored procedures do work and they add records to the tables: a user is added to aspnet_Users, for example.

When I try to use Login.aspx, it crashes on the **manager.Find** with the error: ***"Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'."***

```
    protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            var manager = new UserManager();
            ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing a similar problem in that EntityFramework on VS 2013 generated tables like dbo.AspNetUsers, but when using the aspnet_regsql tool to implement Role Manager functionality, it creates dbo.aspnet_Users.

Comment: Ask.Net Identity uses code first migrations to create it's database tables. Instead of running aspnet_regsql (which would be related to the old membership providers) you want to run a database migration instead.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk - The beauty of the Internet: some tools, such as aspnet_regsql, become outdated but the web pages persist. I ended up with a lotta manual edits and finally got it working.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Migrate from what? Migrate how?

Comment: From the following menu `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`, and then run `Update-Database -ProjectName Project.That.Defines.Context -ConnectionString "CnnStringToDatabase" -ConnectionProviderName System.Data.SqlClient"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The authentication model changed between .Net VS2012 and VS2013, hence the AspNetDB tables and table structures, e.g.

dbo.aspnet_Users become dbo.AspNetUsers with totally different designs and rules (e.g. hyphen forbidden in Username)

Comment: Yep. I figured it out by now. ;)

Comment: @nicomp Accept the answer. You will lose your valuable points anyhow. ;)

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers How do I do that and what happens?

Comment: @nicomp I thought that maybe you thought that by not accepting the answer the bounty would not be subtracted from your point total. That is what I thought in the past once (although at that time there actually was no answer). But if you do not accept an answer your points will disappear anyhow.

Comment: Ah wait I think someone else made a bounty on this. I don't understand. Nevermind!

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers , yes someone else set the bounty. You had me terrified of losing points. My life revolves around these points.

Comment: Mine does too @nicomp. Mine does too.

Comment: @Erwin you are my new best friend