# After .NET Core 2.1 to 3.0 Upgrade, the web api returns empty objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, migration, .net-core-3.0

After upgrading from .net core 2.1 to 3.0, web api is returning empty objects. The API routing works fine, and I can see web trying to return all the objects. However on the chrome's network tab, I can see only empty data objects in response (but the count of objects match what web is trying to return).

Tried looking at Migration issues posted in MSDN but none of them seem to be applicable in this scenario

Similar answers suggested using DataContract/DataMember attributes but that doesn't help.

**Data Model**

```
public class FileDataModel
    {
        public double sNo;
        public DateTime createdDate;
        public string FileName;        

        public FileDataModel(DataRow data)
        {
            sNo = (data["Sno"] == DBNull.Value) ? -1 : (double)data["Sno"];
            createdDate = (DateTime)data["Date"];
            FileName = (string)data["FileName"];           
        }
    }
```

**API Controller (.NET 4.7.2 Class Library)**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {

        static DataController()
        {            
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<FileDataModel>> Get()
        {
            List<FileDataModel> data = FileData.getAllData();
            return data;
        }
    }
```

**.NET Core Project - Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(Assembly.Load("WebApi")).AddControllersAsServices();
```

Expected result is that all the FileDataModel objects are received with full data but what I receive is

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Comment: Try IActionResult instead of ActionResult.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I am getting the error - CS0308 The non-generic type 'IActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: I can't find a source, but I think .net framework and asp.net core 3.0 are no longer compatible. Check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451272/understanding-microsoft-identity-namespaces-system-web-security-microsoft-aspn/58452163#comment103244018_58452163).

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Thanks ! I will check the documentation. I would be surprised if that's the case, since the API routing happens and only the response is not carried over correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that FileDataModel was not exposing the variables as public properties. Once I changed that , it's working.

Comment: feel free to mark it as an answer now, it helped us too

Comment: Me too, muchas gracias